# Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file

Tags: templates

This error keeps vexing me. The file is there, we can see it, the permissions are correct. It's `typelist-theme.xml` in the t4 system plugin, `plugins/system/t4/themes/base/params/typelist-theme.xml`. Funny thing is, this error cannot be reproduced on a local dev setup, only on the live site. We're using the same PHP version, same database dump.

Any tips would be highly appreciated!

Edit, getting xml error:

[{"level":1,"code":1549,"column":0,"message":"failed to load external entity "[ROOT]/plugins/syste
m/t4/themes/base/params/typelist-theme.xml"\n","file":"","line":0}]

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it was an issue with: libxml_disable_entity_loader